# How to use foreach keyword on custom Objects in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

Can someone share a simple example of using the `foreach` keyword with custom objects?

Comment: What specifically is the question? How to *use* foreach with a custom object? Or how to write code in the custom object so that foreach can be used on it?

Comment: how to write code in the custom object so that foreach can be used on it

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Given the tags, I assume you mean in .NET - and I'll choose to talk about C#, as that's what I know about.

The `foreach` statement (usually) uses `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` or their generic cousins. A statement of the form:

```
foreach (Foo element in source)
{
    // Body
}
```

where `source` implements `IEnumerable<Foo>` is *roughly* equivalent to:

```
using (IEnumerator<Foo> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    Foo element;
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        element = iterator.Current;
        // Body
    }
}
```

Note that the `IEnumerator<Foo>` is disposed at the end, however the statement exits. This is important for iterator blocks.

To implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>` yourself, the easiest way is to use an iterator block. Rather than write all the details here, it's probably best to just refer you to [chapter 6 of C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet), which is a free download. The whole of chapter 6 is on iterators. I have another couple of articles on my C# in Depth site, too:

- [Iterators, iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx)
- [Iterator block implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx)

As a quick example though:

```
public IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbers0To10()
{
    for (int i=0; i <= 10; i += 2)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

// Later
foreach (int x in EvenNumbers0To10())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
}
```

To implement `IEnumerable<T>` for a type, you can do something like:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return "x";
        yield return "y";
    }

    // Explicit interface implementation for nongeneric interface
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(); // Just return the generic version
    }
}
```

Comment: The PDF direct link re-directs to the manning page - perhaps this will work better: http://www.manning.com/skeet/

Comment: Thanks very much - fixing now. That's slightly annoying :(

Comment: I'm not too sure that `a implements b` is C# :/ 'm pretty sure that's Java

Comment: @OptimisticPeach: Whoopsy - fixed.

Answer (score 11):

(I assume C# here)

If you have a list of custom objects you can just use the foreach in the same way as you do with any other object:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = // something
foreach(MyObject myObject in myObjects)
{
     // Do something nifty here
}
```

If you want to create your own container you can use the yield keyword (from .Net 2.0 and upwards I believe) together with the IEnumerable interface.

```
class MyContainer : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int max = 0;
    public MyContainer(int max)
    {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
            yield return i;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And then use it with foreach:

```
MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer(10);
foreach(int i in myContainer)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in):

The foreach statement is not limited to `IEnumerable` types and can be applied to an instance of any type that satisfies the following conditions:

has the public parameterless `GetEnumerator` method whose return type is either class, struct, or interface type,
the return type of the `GetEnumerator` method has the public Current property and the public parameterless `MoveNext` method whose return type is Boolean.

If you declare those methods, you can use `foreach` keyword without `IEnumerable` overhead. To verify this, take this code snipped and see that it produces no compile-time error:

```
class Item
{
    public Item Current { get; set; }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class Foreachable
{
    Item[] items;
    int index;
    public Item GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items[index];
    }
}

Foreachable foreachable = new Foreachable();
foreach (Item item in foreachable)
{

}
```