# How do I make a class iterable?

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, iterable

This is my class

```
public class csWordSimilarity
{
    public int irColumn1 = 0;
    public int irColumn2 = 0;
    public int irColumn3 = 0;
    public int irColumn4 = 0;
    public int irColumn5 = 0;
}
```

I want to make that class iterable to be used like the way below

```
foreach (int irVal in myVarWordSimilarity)
{

}
```

`myVarWordSimilarity` is `csWordSimilarity` type. So I want to iterate all public `int` variables. How do I need to modify `csWordSimilarity` class for making it iterable like the way above.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not use `List<int>`? If yes, then look at implementing IEnumerable.

Comment: Reference : [How to use foreach loop with custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/348977/1004522). Go through this and it will also help you understand the usage whenever you want.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can implement IEnumerable and have the GetEnumerator override return an "iterator" over the variables using the [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) statement

```
class csWordSimilarity : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int _var1 = 1;
    private int _var2 = 1;
    private int _var3 = 1;
    private int _var4 = 1;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return _var1;
        yield return _var2;
        yield return _var3;
        yield return _var4;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer though your solution giving error "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? I can't think of a way to replicate that error since .NET 4 allows you to omit the template type definition so it will become an IEnumerable<object>

Comment: it tells me that IEnumerable requires 1 type arguments when I try this

Answer (score 7):

Implement `IEnumerable`. See  [Using Iterators (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators)

In your case you could just use the built-in iterator of a `List` like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class csWordSimilarity : IEnumerable<int> {
    public int irColumn1 = 0;
    public int irColumn2 = 0;
    public int irColumn3 = 0;
    public int irColumn4 = 0;
    public int irColumn5 = 0;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
        return (new List<int>() { 
            irColumn1, irColumn2, irColumn3, irColumn4, irColumn5 
        }).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a considerable overhead in instantiating a new List instance for the sole purpose of returning an enumerator of it, the yield statement simplifies this and is more optimal.

Comment: @edvaldig I think it's a matter of preference. If you're going to call this millions of times, then yes use the direct `yield`. Otherwise I prefer using BCL classes and especially `List` where convenient.