# Advanced collection of collections in C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following classes:

```
class Word { }
class Sentence: List<Word> { }
class TextSection: List<Sentence> { }
class TextBase: List<TextSection> { }
```

And I want to be able to work with `TextBase` as if it was a collection of `Word`s, i.e. iterate over it with `foreach`, use `Select` and `Aggregate` methods.

There are some important additional fields and methods in all of those classes so replacing them with `TextBase: List<Word>` is not an option.

What is the best way to do that?

UPD: Implementing `IEnumerable<Word>` will solve part of my problem, but now when I call `TextBase.Where()` it will return `IEnumerable<Word>` It will ruin my breakdown of base into sections, sections into sentences etc. Can I avoid that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455043/how-do-i-make-a-class-iterable

Comment: @user3554721 do you mean that you want to flatten `TextBase` to list of `Word`?

Comment: @hgulyan Thank you. But see UPD.

Comment: @dkozl Not exactly. I want to work with it as if it was flattened. For instance, filter it with `Where` preserving my breakdown of base into sections, sections into sentences, sentences into words.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `TextBase` implementing both `IEnumerable<TextSection>` (via List) and `IEnumerable<Word>` it is going to be a pain to work with LINQ because you will have to specify types in every LINQ method like `Where` and `Select`. It's best to create a property like `Words` that you can use iterate the words.

Something like:

```
class TextBase : List<TextSection>
{
    public IEnumerable<Word> Words
    {
        get { return this.SelectMany(s => s.Words); }
    }
}

class TextSection : List<Sentence>
{
    public IEnumerable<Word> Words
    {
        get { return this.SelectMany(s => s); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IEnumerable in TextBase:

```
class TextBase: List<TextSection>, IEnumerable<Word>
{     
    IEnumerator<Word> IEnumerable<Word>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((List<TextSection>)this).SelectMany(c => c.SelectMany(w => w)).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `return ((List<TextSection>)this).SelectMany(ts => ts.SelectMany(s => s)).GetEnumerator();`

Answer (score -2):

Why not add a property?

```
    public IEnumerable<Word> Words
    {
        get
        {
            // return all words somehow, maybe using yield
        }
    }
```

Comment: there was such answer 40 minutes ago