# Iterate through LuaTable in c#

Tags: c#, lua, iterator, luainterface

I am trying to iterate through LuaTable object in C#, but getting error.

my lua file is:

```
config = {}
config.visibility = 0
```

and my C# code:

```
LuaTable config = lua.GetTable("config");
Console.WriteLine(config["visibility"].ToString());
foreach (DictionaryEntry member in config)
{
    Console.WriteLine("({0}) {1} = {2}",
        member.Value.GetType().ToString(),
        member.Key,
        member.Value);
}
```

which produces this output:

```
0

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

If I ask just fot value at key `visibility`, I get correct answer, but I am unable to iterate through keys and values.

Which class should I use instead of `DictionaryEntry?`

Thanks,
Zbynek

Comment: the exception occurs during the loop, first time through, right? Which one of the 3 member lines raises the exception?

Comment: error is raised by line with `foreach`

Comment: So compiler is unable to get the dictionary enumerator from config. Does config (ie LuaTable) inherit from IDictionary, and implement the GetEnumerator?

Comment: It does implement `IDictionaryEnumerator`: [https://github.com/NLua/NLua/blob/master/Core/NLua/LuaTable.cs](https://github.com/NLua/NLua/blob/master/Core/NLua/LuaTable.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Well, solution found - following code works:

```
LuaTable tb = lua.GetTable("config");

Dictionary<object, object> dict = lua.GetTableDict(tb);

foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> de in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", de.Key.ToString(), de.Value.ToString());
}
```

I still don't know, why iterating through LuaTable did not work, so I will leave this question open.
Also - If I set types of key and value to something different than `object` (e.g. `string` and `int`), it produces `Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<object,object>'` error.

So for now, I leave this as a workaround and any suggestions will be still welcome.

Comment: You can probably also skip the `dict` object (at least `for each (KeyValuePair<System::Object^, System::Object^> ^d in tb)` worked for me in C++/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Although LuaTable has GetEnumerator/Keys/Values methods, it doesn't inherit from IDictionary. The following might still be applicable: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-01/msg00662.html. See [How to use foreach keyword on custom Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348964/how-to-use-foreach-keyword-on-custom-objects-in-c-sharp) as well. You might have to extend LuaTable or, worse, patch it.

Comment: just updating: `LuaTable` implements `IDictionaryEnumerator` and following works ok: `config.GetEnumerator();`

For some reason, however, foreach loop fails

Comment: @Zbynek Just because it defines the same method isn't sufficient for use with `foreach`. Have you looked at the "how-to" link above?