# How to parse a list of Integers from a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm using "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject" in my application.

I have a method that receives a JObject in the format:

```
{
  "PersonnelIds": "[31,32,33,34]"
}
```

And I want to parse the content of PersonnelIds to a List of Integers.

What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see that the values of the PersonnelIds is written as string `"[31,32,33,34]"` so to parse it with this syntax you can use the following code

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(myjson);
JToken jToken = jObject.GetValue("PersonnelIds");
var array = JArray.Parse(jToken.Value<string>()).Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

if your value is not string so your JSON is like `{"PersonnelIds": [31,32,33,34]
}` then you can parse it using the following code

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(myjson);
JToken jToken = jObject.GetValue("PersonnelIds");
int[] array = jToken.Values<int>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to deserialize your json:

To create classes, you can copy the json in clipboard and use the

```
Edit / Paste special / Paste JSON as class
```

in visual studio (I use vs2013).

Then deserialize your string.

See my solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083585/loop-trought-dictionarystring-object-only-for-a-key-in-c-sharp/28083949#28083949)